# SQLite3 import tsv with one line

Tags: sql, sqlite, for-loop

### Set Up

Ubuntu 18.04 Google VM

### Objective

I'm trying to create a for loop that will import various client files of data into the relevant client table.

### Query test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

set -eu

date=$(date "+%Y%m%d")

for f in $(find $date*.tsv); do
     client=$(echo $f | sed -Ee 's/.csv.tsv//' -e 's/[0-9]+_stuff_stuff_//')
     sqlite3 mydatabase.db "create table if not exists $client (Date integer, Viewability integer, id1 integer, id2 integer, id3 integer, id4 integer, id5 integer, id6 integer, id7 integer, id8 integer, id9 integer, id10 integer, id11 integer, id12 integer, id13 integer, id14 integer, id15 integer, id16 integer, id17 integer, id18 integer, id19 integer, id20 integer);"
     printf ".mode tsv\n.import $f $client\n" | sqlite3 mydatabase.db
done
```

### updated test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

set -eu

date=$(date "+%Y%m%d")

for f in $date*.tsv; do
    client=$(echo "$f" | sed -Ee 's/.csv.tsv//' -e 's/[0-9]+_stuff_stuff_//')
sqlite3 -batch mydatabase.db
<<EOF
"create table if not exists $client (Date integer, Viewability integer, id1 integer, id2 integer, id3 integer, id4 integer, id5 integer, id6 integer, id7 integer, id8 integer, id9 integer, id10 integer, id11 integer, id12 integer, id13 integer, id14 integer, id15 integer, id16 integer, id17 integer, id18 integer, id19 integer, id20 integer);"
.mode tabs
.import "$f" $client
EOF
done
```

## Error

```
    expected 22 columns but found 1 - filling the rest with NULL
```

From what I understood 'sqlite3' doesn't treat new lines in the same way as my initial query looked to run everything on one line with with each command following the other or with ";" separators for new lines. Having researched online people we mentioning that to get the code onto one line I have to change the format to something like what I've used with intentional `\n` breaks. However when I run the code it seems to not read my files as a `tsv` file and as such only finds 1 column. Can someone confirm what I seem to be missing with my code or misunderstanding? I can only assume that it is the format as I can do a manual import without issue but I'm struggling to see why the new code wouldn't be accepted in this format. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The heredoc `<<EOF` needs to be on the same line as the command it's used as standard input to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tsv` is not a mode that the `sqlite3` shell understands. What you should be doing to import a simple tab-delimited file into an existing table is use the **tabs** mode:

```
for f in $date*.tsv; do
    client=$(echo "$f" | sed -Ee 's/.csv.tsv//' -e 's/[0-9]+_stuff_stuff_//')
    sqlite3 -batch mydatabase.db <<EOF
create table if not exists $client (Date integer, Viewability integer, id1 integer, id2 integer, id3 integer, id4 integer, id5 integer, id6 integer, id7 integer, id8 integer, id9 integer, id10 integer, id11 integer, id12 integer, id13 integer, id14 integer, id15 integer, id16 integer, id17 integer, id18 integer, id19 integer, id20 integer);
.mode tabs
.import "$f" $client
EOF
done
```

(I prefer using heredocs over piping the results of a `printf` or `echo` into the shell; makes it a lot easier to read).

In the shell you can use `.help mode` to see the available modes:

```
 sqlite> .help mode
.mode MODE ?TABLE?       Set output mode
   MODE is one of:
     ascii    Columns/rows delimited by 0x1F and 0x1E
     csv      Comma-separated values
     column   Left-aligned columns.  (See .width)
     html     HTML <table> code
     insert   SQL insert statements for TABLE
     line     One value per line
     list     Values delimited by "|"
     quote    Escape answers as for SQL
     tabs     Tab-separated values
     tcl      TCL list elements
```

Comment: I used `.mode tabs` in my original script. I've tried your suggestion but I get the error `test.sh: 30: test.sh: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "done")`

Comment: @El_Birdo EOF shouldn't have been indented. Doh.

Comment: thanks, I tried it without the indent and get the following`Error: near line 1: near ".": syntax error`. It seems to blow up when it gets to the "." in .mode. I thought this might be due to not having the sqlite3 command included in each line but it seems to kick off in either case. Also tried quoting it out thinking it might have been due to "." being expanded.

Comment: @El_Birdo Might have to undent the sqlite commands, too. Or `<<-` and tabs instead of spaces before the commands.

Comment: Yeah, looks like the sqlite3 shell doesn't like space before a .command.

Answer (score 0):

Use `-cmd COMMAND` (run "COMMAND" before reading stdin)

```
sqlite3 -cmd COMMAND <DBFILE> ".import <TSV_FILE> <TABLE_NAME>"
```

## Example

Use tsv

```
sqlite3 -cmd ".mode tsv" ...
```

Create table

```
sqlite3 -cmd "CREATE TABLE ..." ...
```

So, for "Query test.sh":

```
#!/bin/bash

set -eu

date=$(date "+%Y%m%d")

for f in $(find $date*.tsv); do
     client=$(echo $f | sed -Ee 's/.csv.tsv//' -e 's/[0-9]+_stuff_stuff_//')
     init="create table if not exists $client (Date integer, Viewability integer, id1 integer, id2 integer, id3 integer, id4 integer, id5 integer, id6 integer, id7 integer, id8 integer, id9 integer, id10 integer, id11 integer, id12 integer, id13 integer, id14 integer, id15 integer, id16 integer, id17 integer, id18 integer, id19 integer, id20 integer);"
     sqlite3 -cmd ".mode tsv" -cmd "$init" mydatabase.db ".import $f $clinet"
done
```